# Firestore query for find the Airport prefix

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

The result should be an airport name which is between the latitude and longitude range of 3 miles of the present position from the iPhone, just I get a wrong airport in the query.

Code:

```
    let lat = 0.0144927536231884
    let lon = 0.0181818181818182
    let lowerLat = latitude - (lat * distance)
    let lowerLon = longitude - (lon * distance)
    let greaterLat = latitude + (lat * distance)
    let greaterLon = longitude + (lon * distance)
    let docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("airport")
        docRef.whereField("latitude", isGreaterThan: lowerLat)
        .whereField("latitude", isLessThan: greaterLat)
        docRef.whereField("longitude", isGreaterThan: lowerLon)
        .whereField("longitude", isLessThan: greaterLon)
        docRef.getDocuments { snapshot, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
        } else {
            for document in snapshot!.documents {
                if self.btStart.currentTitle == "Decolagem" {
                    self.tfOrigin.text = (document.get("ident") as! String)
                } else {
                    self.tfDestination.text = (document.get("ident") as! String)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

is this query correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things fundamentally wrong with your code. The first is that it doesn't actually query what you're trying to query—all it does is get all of the documents from the airport collection. The second is that it appears you're trying to query for documents using range filters on multiple fields—range filters must all query on the same field.

`docRef` is a reference to a collection (so it really should be called something like `colRef`) which doesn't include any query parameters which is why the query doesn't return anything meaningful, because it isn't exactly a query, it's just a collection grab.

```
docRef.whereField("latitude", isGreaterThan: lowerLat).whereField("latitude", isLessThan: greaterLat)
docRef.whereField("longitude", isGreaterThan: lowerLon).whereField("longitude", isLessThan: greaterLon)
```

The two lines above don't actually do anything since you've declared `docRef` as a constant and you never actually try to change its value. What you're looking for is something like this:

```
let query = Firestore.firestore().collection("airport").whereField("latitude", isGreaterThan: lowerLat).whereField("latitude", isLessThan: greaterLat)

query.getDocuments { snapshot, error in
    ...
}
```

This code would return a meaningful set of documents. However, you cannot add a range filter on another field in this query. When you range filter `latitude`, you've consumed your only available range filter in that query.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have changed it to Geohash. No it's very easy to query. But thank you anyway